# z-index does not work in div under overlay

Tags: html, css

This is an image depicting my problem

[image]

The grey overlay is on top of the body tree and has the following css:

```
overlay{
    z-index: 500;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

The div beneath the overlay (with the top border) has the following css

```
inside_div{
    height: 575px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding:20px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

This class is added to .inside_div dinamically:

```
.inside_div(another_class_added_dinamically){
    outline: none;
    border-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px green;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: glow 0.7s infinite alternate;  
     -webkit-transition: border 0.7s linear, box-shadow 0.7s linear;
       -moz-transition: border 0.7s linear, box-shadow 0.7s linear;
            transition: border 0.7s linear, box-shadow 0.7s linear;
}
```

And **all** elements inside the "inside_div" are added the following class dinamically: (notice the following one affects all children too with the '*')

```
.inside_div(another_class_added_dinamically), .inside_div(another_class_added_dinamically) *{
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

However, as seen in the image, not all elements stand out (the background inside the div remains grey). I would need to know a way of toggling the two previous classes dinamically to highlight the elements as described. What exactly is wrong here? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

From [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Very likely the elements you are giving the z-index do not have position on one of those three.

Hope that helps

Comment: I thought about that, however it does not work... I give position: relative to the elements and some stand out (you can check that in the picture, to the left side) but the background remains grey. Any idea on why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to set the position property on your inside_div element. You should post a fiddle with your code.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with this answer, but your problem could be caused by the fact that your `overlay` div has an opacity `< 1`. As a result, a new `stacking context` is being created, which might explain the behavior you see. It's hard to tell without seeing all of your code. Here is an excellent article explaining `stacking context` in more detail:
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/